# Application hung on loading JSON from FTP, serializing and saving to CoreData [iOS]

Tags: ios, json, core-data, ftp

May be my question looks strange, but... (hope somebody help me)

There are two methods in which I load some data from FTP. Sometimes application hung on these methods.

1. Checking internet connection.
2. If internet avail:

   ```
   @interface Download : NSObject {
       NSOperationQueue *operationQueue;
   }

   ...

   if (!operationQueue) {
       operationQueue = [NSOperationQueue new];
   }

   NSInvocationOperation *operation1;
   operation1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadIngredientsFromJSON) object:nil];
   [operationQueue addOperation:operation1];

   NSInvocationOperation *operation2;
   operation2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(loadRecipesFromJSON) object:nil];
   [operation2 addDependency:operation1];
   [operationQueue addOperation:operation2];

   [operationQueue addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"operations" options:0 context:NULL];
   ```
3. Methods **loadIngredientsFromJSON** & **loadRecipesFromJSON**

   ```
   -(void) loadIngredientsFromJSON
   {
       NSInteger countInBase = [self dataCountInEntity:@"Ingredients"];

       NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ftp://...Ingredients.json"]];
       NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

       NSError *error = nil;
       if (!responseData) {
           return;
       }

       NSDictionary *ingredientsDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
       if (!ingredientsDictionary) {
          return;
       }

       //NSLog(@"%@", [ingredientsDictionary description]);

       NSArray *keys = [ingredientsDictionary allKeys];
       if (!countInBase && [ingredientsDictionary count]>0) {
       AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
       for (int i=0; i<[ingredientsDictionary count]; i++) {
          id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
          NSArray *ingrData = [ingredientsDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aKey]];
          NSArray *tmpArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:aKey, [ingrData objectAtIndex:0], [ingrData objectAtIndex:1], nil];
          Ingredients *ingredient = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ingredients" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];

          ingredient.code = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[[tmpArray objectAtIndex:0] integerValue]];
          ingredient.name = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:1];
          ingredient.units = [tmpArray objectAtIndex:2];
          ingredient.type = [NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
          [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];
       }
       }
   }
   ```

...

```
    - (void) loadRecipesFromJSON
    {        
       NSInteger missedCount = 0;
       NSInteger recipeCode = 0;
       NSString *recipesPath = @"ftp://...";

       do {
         recipeCode ++;
         NSString *recipeFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"recipes/%05d.json", recipeCode];
         NSString *recipeFileFullPath = [recipesPath stringByAppendingString:recipeFileName];

         NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recipeFileFullPath]];
         NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
         NSError *error = nil;
         if (!responseData) {
            missedCount ++;
            continue;
         }
         NSDictionary *recipeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
         if (!recipeDictionary) {
            missedCount ++;
            continue;
         }

         AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

         NSInteger recipeCount = [self isDataExistInEntity:@"Recipes" withCode:[[recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"recipeCode"] integerValue]];
    if (recipeCount == 0) {
        Recipes *recipe = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Recipes" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
        recipe.code = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"recipeCode"];
        recipe.dateUpdated = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"dateEdited"];
        recipe.inCategory = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"inCategory"];
        recipe.name = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"recipe"];
        recipe.difficulty = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"difficulty"];
        recipe.personCount = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"personCount"];
        recipe.prepHour = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"prepHour"];
        recipe.prepMin = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"prepMin"];
        int seconds = ([recipe.prepMin intValue]*60)+([recipe.prepHour intValue] * 60 * 60);
        recipe.prepTime = [NSNumber numberWithInt: seconds];
        recipe.isPaid = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"isPaid"];
        recipe.comment = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"comments"];

        NSDictionary *ingredients = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"ingredients"];
        NSArray *keys = [ingredients allKeys];
        if ([keys count] > 0) {
            for (int i=0; i<[keys count]; i++) {
                Join *join = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Join" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                join.recipeCode = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"recipeCode"];

                id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
                join.ingredientCode = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[aKey integerValue]];

                NSString *str = [ingredients objectForKey:aKey];
                double num = [str doubleValue];
                join.count = [NSNumber numberWithDouble:num];

                join.inCart = [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
            }
        }

        NSDictionary *prepStages = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"prepStage"];
        keys = [prepStages allKeys];
        if ([keys count] > 0) {
            for (int i=0; i<[keys count]; i++) {
                PrepStages *prepStage = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PrepStages" inManagedObjectContext:appDelegate.managedObjectContext];
                prepStage.recipeCode = [recipeDictionary objectForKey:@"recipeCode"];

                id aKey = [keys objectAtIndex:i];
                prepStage.order = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[aKey integerValue]];
                prepStage.descriptions = [prepStages objectForKey:aKey];

                //загрузка картинки
                NSString *recipeImageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"recipeImages/%05d-%@.jpg", recipeCode, [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[aKey integerValue]]];
                NSString *recipeImageFullPath = [recipesPath stringByAppendingString:recipeImageName];
                NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recipeImageFullPath]];
                if (request) {
                    NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

                    if (responseData) {
                        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
                        prepStage.image = image;
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        [appDelegate.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }
    else {
        missedCount ++;
        continue;
    }

    } while (missedCount < 10);
    }
```

Sometimes in one of these two methods application hung and control freeze.

Can anybody give me some advice in which line there may be the bug.

I confused...

**EDITED**

I noticed interesting thing:

Download process starts when app run. It downloads **Recipes** from server and inserts them to CoreData. If I tap to see **recipe list** I use `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` to fetch data. Download also uses `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` when it want to insert data.

Can this contain problem?

Comment: You really wrote a lot of code, Why don't you just use 'AFNetworking' (https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) and make your life easier.

Comment: @Tarek: this is just a part of code ))

Comment: You need to narrow down where the app is freezing. Try setting breakpoints in these methods and stepping through them to see where the freeze occurs.

Comment: I have already used breakpoints, but app freezes not in the same line of code ((
may be some problem with `NSOperationQueue` or `NSInvocationOperation`?