# Application hung [iOS]

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobjectcontext

Continue of question [Application hung on loading JSON from FTP, serializing and saving to CoreData [iOS]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16933491/application-hung-on-loading-json-from-ftp-serializing-and-saving-to-coredata-i?noredirect=1#comment24467352_16933491)

When application starts it starts download data from ftp and save downloaded data to CoreData entity. Application hung only If I jump to list of recipes during download process.

So I guess that problem is **use the same NSManagedObjectContext**: when I save downloaded data to CoreData I use `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` and if I want to see list of recipes I also use `appDelegate.managedObjectContext` for fetching data.

My question is: should I create another `NSManagedObjectContext` for downloading data? Or may be there is some correct way to prevent app's freeze?

Thanks for any helpful advice.

Comment: Cocoanetics has an interesting read on this: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/07/multi-context-coredata/ and a fllow up on locking: http://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/zarra-on-locking/

Comment: @rckoenes: it looks like what I need, but I don't quietly understand what should I do...

Comment: Using a separate managed object context is probably a good idea, but it's impossible to say whether this would help with the app freezing. What have you done to determine the cause? "I guess" is a good way to waste a lot of time trying random things.

Comment: @TomHarrington: Tom, app freezes ONLY when I jump to `UIViewController` which fetch the list of recipes, and downloading process works with this list of recipes too... so I "guess" that some bug in transaction